# I get a NullPointerException when executing the android tutorial source code

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

I have searched for my issue here and in google with little success.  I have come close, but not quite found my issue.  So I am new to Android development and I can't figure out where I am wrong here.  I am doing the tutorial for [Starting Another Activity](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html) on the developer.android.com site.

Here is my `MainActivity.java`:

```
package com.example.myfirstapp;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.example.myfirstapp.MESSAGE";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    /** Called when the user clicks the Send button */
    public void sendMessage(View view){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
        EditText editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
        String message = editText.getText().toString();
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

The line `String message = editText.getText().toString();` in the IDE says it may throw a `Java.lang.NullPointerException`.  When I run the app, it loads, then crashes.

Here is my `activity_main.xml`:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">




    <EditText android:id="@+id/edit_message"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:hint="@string/edit_message" />

    <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/button_send"
            android:onClick="sendMessage" />

    <activity
            android:name="com.example.myfirstapp.DisplayMessageActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_display_message"
            android:parentActivityName="com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity" >
        <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity" />
    </activity>
</LinearLayout>
```

Here is my DisplayMessageActivity.java:

```
package com.example.myfirstapp;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.NavUtils;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.TextView;


/**
 * Created by rvance on 5/16/13.
 */
public class DisplayMessageActivity extends Activity {
    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Get the message from the intent
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String message = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);

        TextView textView = new TextView(this);
        textView.setTextSize(40);
        textView.setText(message);

        // Set the text view as the activity layout
        setContentView(textView);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
                return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Here is my AndroidManifest.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.myfirstapp"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="Russell's First App"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".DisplayMessageActivity" android:label="activity_display_message"/>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

The problem seems to me to be in the sendMessage() method in the MainActivity class.  Specifically the line `String message = editText.getText().toString();`

```
/** Called when the user clicks the Send button */
public void sendMessage(View view){
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
    EditText editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
    String message = editText.getText().toString(); // The line that crashes is here
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

In the end, I have no doubt I screwed up somewhere, but I do not see where. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: `<Activity>` tag is added to manifest. look for AndroidManifest.xml in your project and add there. Remember to post the log-cat too while you are getting any exception.

Comment: well, check what is null. Is the editText null, or does getText() simply return null?

Comment: Please post the stack trace of the error from LogCat.

Comment: You should (nearly) always post the logcat stack trace when asking about a crash.  The stack trace (nearly) always takes you directly to the cause.  You should also learn how to use the debugger.  It's a vital skill and with it, you could find this bug in 30 seconds.

Comment: Are you sure the app crashes on loading, and not when you click the button? (That kind of stuff is essential and you can probably find that out by looking at the stack trace).

Comment: @Eric  `<activity            android:name="com.example.myfirstapp.DisplayMessageActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_display_message"
         android:parentActivityName="com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity" >
        <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity" />
    </activity>`  Activity tag in layout Xml file? I haven't tried till now, have you?

Answer (score 0):

In your `DisplayMessageActivity` try:

```
String message = intent.getExtras().getString(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);
```

Instead of your:

```
String message = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);
```

Comment: This fix would not help a `NullPointerException`, as the only thing that would raise it here would be `intent`, which you reference as well.